# Magento 2 - All admin grid keeps loading

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, error, grid

In my Magento 2.4.1, all the admin grid just keeps loading. No data is rendering. Showing a js error in console but I don't understand what's wrong. If anyone ever faced this please let me know what's wrong.

**Note: I have regenerated vendor file, disabled all modules still issue persist.**

See the error below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'items')
at UiClass.onRequestComplete (eval at require.load (static.min.js:11:216), <anonymous>:8:140)
at fire (eval at require.load (static.min.js:11:216), <anonymous>:214:223)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (eval at require.load (static.min.js:11:216), <anonymous>:220:181)
at done (eval at require.load (static.min.js:11:216), <anonymous>:630:95)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (eval at require.load (static.min.js:11:216), <anonymous>:657:15)
```

[image]

Comment: hello, dear, you can see the below link.I think that is helpful for you.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Uncaught-TypeError-Cannot-read-property-items-of-null-for/td-p/128247